# Não consigo acessar meu projeto Laravel 5 pelo Vagrant e Nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, vagrant

Estou criando um ambiente de desenvolvimento usando o **Vagrant** com as seguintes dependências:

- PHP7;
- PostgreSQL 9.3;
- Nginx 1.9;
- Git.

O problema é que ao acessar a url `http://advodocs.local.com/` o Chrome me retorna:

> A página de advodocs.local.com não está funcionando
>
> advodocs.local.com não consegue atender a esta solicitação no momento.

E acessando o log do Nginx eu tenho o seguinte:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/vagrant/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#2 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)
#3 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(202): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)
#4 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(113): Illuminate\Log\Writer->write
2017/01/06 01:58:23 [error] 2107#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/vagrant/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#2 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#3 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(202): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#4 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(113): Illuminate\Log\Writer->writeLog('error', Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#5 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Ex...
```

## Explicando a configuração do ambiente

### Hosts

Em meu computador eu editei o `/etc/hosts` e inseri `192.168.68.20 advodocs.local.com`.

### Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    # Customiza propriedades do Vagrant
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 2524]
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", 1]
    end

    # Escolhe a box
    config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'

    # Configura port forwarding
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080, auto_correct: true
    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.68.20"

    #Inicia o provisionamento
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/init.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/php.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/postgres.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/nginx.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/node.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision/git.sh"
end
```

#### init.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y

sudo apt-get install --reinstall -y \
    language-pack-en \
    language-pack-pt

sudo apt-get install -y \
    python-software-properties \
    build-essential \
    zip \
    unzip \
    software-properties-common
```

#### php.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y \
    php7.0-fpm \
    php7.0-mysql \
    curl \
    php7.0-mbstring \
    php-xml

sudo cp /vagrant/provision/php/php.ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini

sudo service php7.0-fpm restart

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

composer self-update
```

#### nginx.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y \
    nginx

sudo service nginx start

# set up nginx server
sudo cp /vagrant/provision/nginx/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo chmod 644 /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
sudo service nginx reload
sudo service nginx restart

# clean /var/www
sudo rm -Rf /var/www

# symlink /var/www => /vagrant
ln -s /vagrant /var/www

chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
chmod -R 775 /var/www/storage
```

#### /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

Eu modifiquei apenas a parte abaixo desse arquivo:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name advodocs.local.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

#### php.ini

Eu apenas modifiquei uma parte para `cgi.fix_pathinfo=0`

## Resumindo

Como podem ver, baixo as dependências, copio os arquivos de configuração do Nginx e PHP pra pasta deles quando a VM subir e dou as devidas permissões na pasta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de procurar bastante conseguie a resposta. Esse é um "problema" do Vagrant, que acaba ficando como dono de todas as pastas, assim modificando algumas permissões. O certo para a execução do PHP é que o `www-data` seja o dono, então foi só mudar no arquivo `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant",
owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"

config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www",
owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Permission denied in /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107

olá, tente dar permissão para o diretório informado.

com a VM on, use o

```
sudo chmod 644 /vagrant/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/
```